# How to put multiple windows in fullscreen at once in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, fullscreen, pysimplegui

I am trying to create a few windows, which I need all of them to be in fullscreen. I am aware of .Maximize() but I can't get it work properly in this code. Any ideas? Thank you!

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def make_window1():
    layout = [[sg.Text('Window 1')],
              [sg.Button('Next >'), sg.Button('Exit')]]

    return sg.Window('Window 1', layout, finalize=True).Finalize()


def make_window2():
    layout = [[sg.Text('Window 2')],
               [sg.Button('Next >'), sg.Button('Exit')]]

    return sg.Window('Window 2', layout, finalize=True).Finalize()


window1, window2 = make_window1(), None

while True:
    window, event, values = sg.read_all_windows()
    window.Maximize()
    if window == window1 and event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break

    if window == window1:
        if event == 'Next >':
            window1.hide()
            window2 = make_window2()

    if window == window2 and event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break


window.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call method `maximize()` of window after it finalized.

Four ways here to show the switching of windows.

1. New window created with different layout.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def make_window1():
    layout = [[sg.Text('Window 1')],
              [sg.Button('Next >'), sg.Button('Exit')]]
    window = sg.Window('Window 1', layout, finalize=True)
    window.maximize()
    return window

def make_window2():
    layout = [[sg.Text('Window 2')],
               [sg.Button('Next >'), sg.Button('Exit')]]
    window = sg.Window('Window 1', layout, finalize=True)
    window.maximize()
    return window

window, now = make_window1(), 1

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
    elif event == 'Next >':
        win, now = (make_window1(), 1) if now == 2 else (make_window2(), 2)
        window.close()
        window = win

window.close()
```

2. Dual window created at same time and decide which shown on screen.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def make_window1():
    layout = [[sg.Text('Window 1')],
              [sg.Button('Next >'), sg.Button('Exit')]]
    window = sg.Window('Window 1', layout, finalize=True)
    return window


def make_window2():
    layout = [[sg.Text('Window 2')],
               [sg.Button('Next >'), sg.Button('Exit')]]
    window = sg.Window('Window 1', layout, finalize=True)
    return window

window1, window2 = make_window1(), make_window2()
window1.maximize()
window2.hide()

while True:

    window, event, values = sg.read_all_windows()

    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
    elif event == 'Next >':
        window.hide()
        window = window1 if window == window2 else window2
        window.un_hide()
        window.maximize()

window1.close()
window2.close()
```

3. Using `sg.Column` with attribute `visible` True or False

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def swap(now, step):
    window[f'COLUMN {now}'].update(visible=False)
    now = (now+step) % total
    window[f'COLUMN {now}'].update(visible=True)
    return now

def column_layout(index):
    layout = [[sg.Text(f'Window {index+1}')]]
    return layout

total, now = 5, 0

sg.theme("DarkBlue")
sg.set_options(font=('Courier New', 16))

layout = [
    [sg.Column(column_layout(i), visible=(i==0), key=f'COLUMN {i}') for i in range(total)],
    [sg.VPush()],
    [sg.Button('< PREV'), sg.Push(), sg.Button('Exit'), sg.Push(), sg.Button('NEXT >')],
]

window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)
window.maximize()

while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event==sg.WINDOW_CLOSED or event.startswith('Exit'):
        break
    elif event in ("< PREV", "NEXT >"):
        now = swap(now, 1 if event == "NEXT >" else -1)

window.close()
```

Using `sg.TabGroup`

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def tab_layout(index):
    layout = [[sg.Text(f'Window {index+1}')]]
    return layout

sg.theme("DarkBlue")
sg.set_options(font=('Courier New', 16))

total, now = 5, 0

tab_group = [[sg.Tab(f"TAB {i}", tab_layout(i), key=f"TAB {i}")] for i in range(5)]
layout = [
    [sg.TabGroup(tab_group, border_width=0, pad=(0, 0), expand_x=True, expand_y=True, key='TABGROUP')],
    [sg.VPush()],
    [sg.Button('< PREV'), sg.Push(), sg.Button('Exit'), sg.Push(), sg.Button('NEXT >')],
]
window = sg.Window("Title", layout, finalize=True)
style = sg.ttk.Style()
style.layout('TNotebook.Tab', [])                           # Hide tab bar
window.maximize()

while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, "Exit"):
        break
    elif event in ("< PREV", "NEXT >"):
        now = (now+1)%total if event == "NEXT >" else (now-1)%total
        window[f"TAB {now}"].select()

window.close()
```

Comment: Excellent, Jason. That solved my problem. Nevertheless, I have a new problem within this question:

What I need to do is to have one window which is refreshing every time there is a click (pretty much like working inside a folder in Windows or making an installation, where the same window refreshes every time there is a click.

Is there a way I can do that with PySimpleGUI? Because by closing a window and opening a new one, there are a few milliseconds where that change of window is very notorious.

Regards,
Iván